# Translation(s) of "out of town"?

Tags: expressions, anglais

There seem to be several ways in French to translate **out of town**, but which captures the general idea of just being **away**, not necessarily in the countryside (à la campagne), or in another town (dans une autre ville), or somewhere near town (à l'extérieur?)?

And, to be clear, I don't mean **out *on* the town**, which is a completely different activity.

Answer (score 4):

There is no word-for-word equivalent to *out of town* when it boils down to indicating someone is away.
In every day language, some standards phrases would be:

> Il n'est pas là
>
> Il est parti
>
> Il s'est absenté (a bit more formal)
>
> Il est en déplacement (used in business contexts, for jobs that involve a lot of traveling)

You could come across *il n'est pas en ville*, but the meaning is more restricted than in English: it implies that this person usually stays in the city, and that they are temporarily gone to the countryside or to another city, or even just to the suburbs ("en ville" often implies "downtown" in French).

Comment: @Emma Dans la langue parlée ça ne se dit pas; dans la langue littéraire moderne, qui doit reproduire de la langue parlée, ça ne se dit pas non plus; lorsqu' appliqué à autre chose qu'une personne, alors dans la langue littéraire cela se trouve ; c'est  correct, idiomatique : . Dans la langue littéraire, « hors » est utilisé beaucoup pour des concepts autres que le lieu : hors du temps, hors de lui, hors des chemins battus (figuré) …  (faire  l'ngram « * hors de la ville »).

Comment: @Emma « Ne savais pas que » n'est pas français; peut être vous voulez dire « je ne savais pas cela ! » ; dites-vous que vous ne connaissez pas les ngram ?

Comment: @Emma Ne jamais demander pardon ou s'excuser pour cela, vos erreurs ne nous blessent en aucune façon; vous pouvez, et c'est si vous le désirez, dire merci à la personne qui vous fourni la correction à une erreur ; en général elle fait cela avec bon cœur et pas dans l'idée de recevoir un merci; d'ailleurs les mercis sont découragés : il ne faudrait pas faire un commentaire pour un merci seulement, mais, néanmoins il m'arrive d'en faire moi-même, et je ne suis pas le seul.  By the way, it's « Pardonnes-moi/Pardonnez-moi ».

Comment: @Emma The ngram site: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=

Answer (score 1):

"Hors de ville" is not a locution in the language; all you can find are normal free constructions: hors de **la** ville, hors des villes, hors d'une ville. However, there exists a meaning of the preposition "hors" that is proper ;

> (TLFi) 1. En dehors de (un espace)
>
> - **Hors barrière**
> - Ce pan de chemise hors la culotte du gamin.
> - Les bêtes broutent hors les bergeries, mais ne s'éparpillent plus.
> - Les Templiers avaient le leur [un port] non loin de la place de Grève, et la rue du Temple avait été initialement ouverte pour relier à ce port leurs établissements **hors murs**, situés dans la région nord.

In the examples one notices "hors barrière" et "hors murs" in which no article figures; those are ready made locutions, issued from "hors la barrière" "hors des murs"; after some time of using them a lot they have been shorten, so that quite possibly le long form is not correct (I couldn't assert whether yes or no, though).

You'd have to say then "**hors la ville**".

However, the proposed translation belongs to the literary style; in everyday language a simple phrase is used, « pas en ville », « hors de la ville », according to the context.

*after a verb, as a complement*

- Lorsqu'il n'est **pas en ville** il est à la chasse.
- Quand les ouvriers ne travaillent pas en ville il reçoivent un bonus.

*as an adjectival locution*

- Leurs propriétés **hors de la ville** consistent en deux fermes d'élevage.

An [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+pas+en+ville&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20pas%20en%20ville%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bn%27est%20pas%20en%20ville%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bn%27%C3%A9tait%20pas%20en%20ville%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%AEne%20pas%20en%20ville%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bn%27entreront%20pas%20en%20ville%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%AEnait%20pas%20en%20ville%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsont%20pas%20en%20ville%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnon%20pas%20en%20ville%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bva%20pas%20en%20ville%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brestent%20pas%20en%20ville%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btrouve%20pas%20en%20ville%3B%2Cc0) tends to confirm those claims.

In this second case, one can sometimes hear this ;

- Leurs propriétés **<s>pas en ville</s>** consistent en deux fermes d'élevage.

It's not correct, but is acceptable when repeating for a person who has difficulties in French, particularly a foreigner; nevertheless, the full sentence is not repeated often: « pas en ville », « les propriétés pas en ville ».

Answer (score 0):

On the Ask a question page, one is advised and can choose (using the tick box)...

> Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style

I chose to do this, after giving my original question some more thought; hence my second question. I will reframe it in deference to @Stéphane Gimenez and @Toto who chose to delete it (in contravention of Stack Exchange's advice).

Perhaps **hors de ville** is a suitable phrase to mean *away somewhere not close to town*.

Comment: Sorry, but I have never heard the expression *hors de ville* and it looks very strange to me. I know the expression *hors de la ville* , but it corresponds for example to houses just besides (and out of) the city. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Il existe aussi l'expression **être à l'extérieur** qui selon le contexte a différentes significations, et qui se rapproche quelque peu de la signification de **out of town**. 
**Il est à l'extérieur** peut signifier par exemple

- il n'est pas à la maison
- il n'est pas dans les locaux de l'entreprise
- il n'est pas en ville
- il est à l'étranger